# Deleting Woocommerce webhooks via cronjob

Tags: wordpress, cron, woocommerce

I am using Wooocommerce and an invoice/product inventory system which is implemented via Woocommerce API. I need live synchronization but the problem with this is that the inventory system is adding thousands of webhooks while synchronizing, which is making the site extremely slow. Does anyone know if it is possible to set up a cronjob to delete all webhooks in certain intervals?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to setup a cronjob to delete all web-hooks. You can also delete a single or batch delete the web-hook. [Here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#batch-update-webhooks) is the documentation link for batch and single web-hook [delete](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#delete-a-webhook) link.